# Business Intelligence Sample Data or Database

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, powerbi

I don't know I should ask this question over here. I know it can be marked too broad or marked as close.

I have started learning BI and data analysis. I search on internet I found some good tools which I am interested QlikView  & PowerBI.

I like some help from you guys like Sample data where I can play around and some scenarios. If I get some website or some tips to learn.

I will very much appreciate for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Power BI:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/it-it/desktop/

Sign up (free) and Microsoft will give you sample data to use and see on Power BI.

If you are interested in the single component:

- Excel 2013 Power Pivot: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399078(v=sql.110).aspx or https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Tutorial-Extend-Data-Model-relationships-using-Excel-Power-Pivot-and-DAX-cf7197d3-1938-490e-93fb-20371e8dd67a (I prefer this one)
- Excel 2013 Power Query:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-Query-101-008b3f46-5b14-4f8b-9a07-d3da689091b5 or https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-Help-2b433a85-ddfb-420b-9cda-fe0e60b82a94
- Excel 2013 Power View: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Tutorial-Create-Amazing-Power-View-Reports-Part-1-e2842c8f-585f-4a07-bcbd-5bf8ff2243a7
- Power BI Desktop: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

Try the Lahman baseball database. A number of R scrips exist w/ output, so that you can compare your analysis from whatever tool you used.

Answer (score 1):

Once you sign up at www.qlik.com there is a documentation and tutorial download in their download section for each of their products. The complete version of the tutorial includes a data set that will get you going

Answer (score 0):

Qlik sense has a desktop version which is free to try and comes with sample data. Its easy to get started with! http://www.qlik.com/products/qlik-sense/desktop

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

For both Qlikview and Qlik Sense you can download their free desktop app.

Afterwards you can install the Google [Bigquery ODBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/) and access the Bigquery public dataset. In fact it is beneficial to simply learn BI using Google Bigquery.

Follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/analyzing-nyc-biking-data-with-google-bigquery) to see how you can retrieve/manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can find QlikView and Qlik Sense demos in this link:

http://eu-a.demo.qlik.com/

Both applications are fully free to use for personal use and I would suggest you start your Qlik journey with Qlik Sense. It is their latest product where you can create applications and even share them with your friends through Qlik Cloud.

Definitely worth a go.